# Literature with regards to facial attractiveness?

Tags: social-psychology, reference-request, physical-attraction

I would like to ask for suggestions of literature regarding the study of facial features, preferably in a context of how they may be considered attractive or not.

To clarify, the goal is to try and gain an understanding of what distinct facial features exist, and of what variation exists regarding each of them (in lengths, angles, other topographical aspects), and of how those features combine into more visually complex features, etc. This is for no particular purpose other than just my own curiosity.

Comment: There's a show called "Brain games" on Netflix, which deals with a lot of popular cognitive neuroscience. They have a number of episodes dealing with faces and facial recognition. An interesting takeaway was - people could predict the outcome of local elections based on simply seeing pictures of 2 candidates. The accuracy was around 70% with no information other than the picture. This shows you how hard wired we are to process faces and project qualities onto them.  Highly recommend that show :)

Comment: You can search face reading, that will give you more than just the combinations.

Comment: Have you done any initial search? It is my impression there are tons of resources available on this, even in popular science. Just yesterday I saw a video in my news feed on attractiveness. E.g., average faces (averaged of multiple input pictures) consistently score higher. I recommend doing some initial research (popular scientific reporting is okay!) and then ask a more specific question.